# How to accept delimiters (: , ., /, ?, =, +, -, _,) inside a regex to match a string value Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have input strings I'm trying to validate. 
I may have some delimiters between "abc 123" and "abcd 123", i.e possible scenarios:

```
str = "abc-123 abcd 123";
str = "abc/123 abcd 123";
str = "abc&&123 abcd 123";
str = "abc:123 abcd 123";
str = "abc.123 abcd 123";
etc.....
```

Basically I want to consider all these strings as valid inout string

My regex:

```
var m = value.match(/([a-z]+\s*\d+)\s+([a-z]+\s*\d+|\d+\s*[a-z]+)/i);
if (m) {return "valid string"}
else {return "invalid string"}
```

Currently my regex throws "invalid string" for the above listed scenarios except for whitespaces

`( str= "User 123") // return valid string`

how can I add a condition in my regex to evaluate all the above scenarios to true?

```js
function testIt(value) {
  var m = value.match(/([a-z]+\s*\d+)\s+([a-z]+\s*\d+|\d+\s*[a-z]+)/i);
  if (m) {return "valid string"}
  else {return "invalid string"}
}

console.log(testIt("abc-123 abcd 123"));
console.log(testIt("abc/123 abcd 123"));
console.log(testIt("abc&&123 abcd 123"));
console.log(testIt("abc:123 abcd 123"));
console.log(testIt("abc.123 abcd 123"));
```

Comment: I made you a [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either put all possible characters into a character set between the `[a-z]+` and the `\d+`:

```
([a-z]+[\s\/&:.-]*\d+)\s+([a-z]+\s*\d+|\d+\s*[a-z]+)
       ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

https://regex101.com/r/HJg1cE/1

Or, repeat any non-digit characters until you get to a digit character (if indeed any non-digit character is permitted there):

```
([a-z]+\D*\d+)\s+([a-z]+\s*\d+|\d+\s*[a-z]+)
       ^^^
```